# Change Host Named Site Collection Url

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, host-named

How can I change the host name site collection from http:// to https://?

**eg: http://sp1 to https://sp1**

I checked this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/svarukala/2014/05/06/change-host-named-site-collection-url/ but it's not help.

Comment: what error u are getting?

Comment: 403 error!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Try to change the Site Collection via PowerShell as shown below

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity http://sp1
$site.Rename("https://sp1")
```

Second, Make sure that the URL is working first inside the server properly.

**Note:** Make sure you already add the hostname in your drivers folder by Navigating `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, Open hosts file via appropriate editor > add the current server IP > click Tab from keyboard >add the hostname.

In case, it's worked inside the server but not worked outside. so you should check with a load balancer and network team.

In case it's not worked inside the server,

- Try to backup your site collection `Backup-SPSite -Identity <SiteCollectionGUIDorURL> -Path <BackupFile>`
- Delete the site collection.
- Create a new one and restore your site collection